# Python: first test program

Tags: python, macos

I have copied and pasted the below code into a textwrangler file called "ex1.py" which i have saved to my desktop (mac) and then into a directory called mystuff etc but the compiler can't seem to find the file..I've tried maybe 50 times...

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

I receive an error 'no such file directory' when i run "python ex1.py" (ex1.py is the name of the test program). Or when i type "python" in the terminal first to get the current version info, then type "python ex1.py" i get a syntax error: invalid syntax. Should i create a new directory like 'mystuff' and navigate to it first when compiling from the terminal? (i thought you didn't have to compile python anyhow) Please help thanks.

Here is the specific error

```
>>> python ex1.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python ex1.py
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried navigating to the file by inputing "python, ^D, mkdir my stuff, cd mystuff, ls, python ex1.py still no file found (i dragged the file manually to the file btw)

Yes idle works great thanks. Should one do all 'compiling' for python there seeing as my mac terminal had trouble finding the files (and still can't) thanks though.

thanks for the help. Python works in mysterious ways. Now lets share the good cheer and one of you blokes rate me up. -2? cmon son -_-

Got it to work in terminal also by navigating to the directory (python, ^D, cd mystuff, ls, cd newfolder, python ex1.py. worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: It's not a compiler; `python ex1.py` means "use `python` to run `ex1.py`" (and there's a difference between an instruction to the terminal and python code). If you don't navigate to the folder the script is in, how is the terminal supposed to find it?

Comment: Have you tried using IDLE? Open up the interpreter, play around in there, then click File>New File. When you finish typing in your program into the file, save it, then press Fn-F5. Your program will run!

Comment: Python is not compiled, you are correct. When you type in `python` into the terminal, it takes you to the python interpreter. Try typing `print 'Hello World!'` after you typed `python` in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try idle. Recompiling in progress...

Comment: after i get it to work maybe lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python is not compiled, you are correct. When you type in `python` into the terminal, it takes you to the python interpreter. Try typing `print 'Hello World!'` after you have typed `python` in the terminal.

Have you tried using IDLE? Open up the interpreter (IDLE) from your launchpad, play around in there, then click File>New File. When you finish typing in your program into the file, save it, then press Fn-F5. Your program will run!

EDIT: `python ex1.py` is not valid syntax, hence the `SyntaxError`. When you see the `>>>` prompt, it means you are using the python interpreter, not the terminal. If you want to run a python file from the terminal type `python ex1.py` into the *terminal* and not the *python interpreter*. And make sure that you are in the right directory in the terminal so that you can access the python file.

Answer (score 4):

You have two entirely separate problems here.

1. `python ex1.py` is *not* valid Python, hence the `SyntaxError`; it is an instruction to the Terminal command line, meaning "use the `python` program to run the `ex1.py` file". The language in which you interact with the Terminal *isn't* Python; and
2. When given that instruction, Terminal needs to *find* the file you specify. Finding `python` is easy, as it's installed, but the file could be anywhere.

You have two possible solutions:

1. As others have suggested, switch to using an IDE (e.g. IDLE, which comes with Python) and run your file through that instead; or
2. Use `cd` ("change directory") to navigate, inside Terminal, to the location in which the file is stored (you should see `ex1.py` in the list when you run `ls`), *then* you can run `python ex1.py`.

As you are clearly ["Learn[ing] Python the Hard Way"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex1.html), I would **strongly recommend** the latter. Read the warning in and follow steps 9 and 10 of [exercise zero](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html).

Oh, and you're right that Python isn't compiled; it's interpreted, which is why you have to specify the *interpreter* (`python`) in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the promt you show, it looks like you are trying to execute your program from *inside* the Python shell/interpreter. Try this instead at the `>>>` prompt:

```
execfile('ex1.py')
```

or alternatively from your shell command line do what you did:

```
python ex1.py
```

Nothing wrong with using IDLE, but you can run your programs from the command line too just fine.

If you decide to work more frequently with the Python interpreter, consider using [iPython](http://ipython.org/), it offers command line completion and good online help.

Answer (score 0):

When >>> is on a screen means you are in a python environment.
Exit from there by typing quit command

> > > quit()

Now you will back into the terminal.

Go to the directory where you have saved the ex1.py file and from there execute the command

python ex1.py